# Add Swipe Gesture to all View controllers in the project

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, swipe-gesture

I have set of 50 view controllers with back button. Now I need to add Left to Right swipe gesture for all view controllers in the project. When a swipe is triggered, I need to call back btn clicked event for respective view controller. It is difficult to add swipe gesture to each view controller. Is there any other way to do it with minimal changes to view controllers.
   Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Bharath G

Comment: How you added 50 ViewControllers. in `UIScrollView` , `UIPageViewController` or any other ? or you want to integrate popviewController functionality when swipe.

Comment: View controllers are managed using navigation controller(push,pop). Each back button has its own implementation in its view controllers. On swipe left, respective view controllers back btn clicked event should be called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well these other guys have told you why you may not need to do this, but assuming you do (not using UINavigationController || supporting pre iOs7 ..) then surely the easiest way to add to all of them would be to make a new UIViewController subclass, add the swipeRecogniser in viewDidLoad or similar, and then modify each of your 50 other controllers so that they all inherit from this one (i.e. abstract superclass..)

I would always have an abstract superclass above UIViewController in a project with 50 or so, obviously there is plenty of code that can be shared

Comment: From super class, how to call child class back button clicked event method?

Comment: @bharathgangupalli You are looking at it wrong. The superclass will call its own implementation of back button event handler which can be empty. The subclass will override it.

Comment: yes the swipe might call an action e.g. -(void)swipeRight:(UIGestureRecogniser *)sender   on self.  But your concrete subclasses can override this with their own implementations..

Comment: Ya.. Got it Jef. Thanks for the solution.

Answer (score 2):

Create a `YourViewController` class and implement your SwipeGesture method in viewDidLoad method.

In your 50 viewcontrollers .h file:

```
@interface ViewController : YourViewController
```

Let all your 50 viewControllers inherit from your `YourViewController`.

Comment: Maybe an extension will be better. Since you can inherits from only one class. With your solution you will need to subclass UIViewController, UITableViewController etc.
SO an extension that add a method to UIViewController. and just add the call to this method in your 50 viewControllers viewDidLoad.

Comment: this is pretty much an exact duplicate of the answer above it, which was around ten minutes earlier..

Answer (score 0):

It should work automatically if the back button is visible. If you are displaying a leftBarButtonItem instead of the back button, the gesture will not be present by default. Also, if you are using a UINavigationBar but not a UINavigationController, you won't see this functionality.

If you are using a UINavigationController and your view controller's navigation item contains a leftBarButtonItem, it's still possible to add functionality for the swipe left to right gesture of the navigation controller, by attaching a delegate to the navigation controller's interactivePopGestureRecognizer.

Note: The Swipe to Back feature is introduced with iOS 7(i Hope you are Developing App fos iOS 7 or later)